# catching Talend error in web Application

Tags: web-services, axis, etl, talend

I have created a Talend job and deployed it as a Axis Web Service.
I am calling this Web Service from my Web Application.
My application and web service are deployed over Tomcat server.

For Valid Inputs:
Runs Perfectly.

For Invalid Inputs:
It throws Error/exceptions in Tomcat Server.

I want this Errors into my application. I didn't get any error related information in the Response sent by web service.

**Error message on Tomcat Server**

[image]

**XML response of Web service**

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the job design?

Comment: As I cant upload more than two links ,I will explain you my  simple job, its getting input from excel file and loading into database. Database Table have ID column which is INT ,and from excel if we gave text value it doesnt accept and throws error. Job design is simply like this :-  tFileInputExcel--->> tMap---->>tMSSqlOutput

Comment: can you post the code from your service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question you are not so much asking how to fix this error, but how to get feedback about your error.  There are several ways but here is a simple method.

Add a `tLogCatcher` to your job, and point its output to a `tSendMail` component.  You can run the output thru a `tMap` do things like adding `HTML` formatting.  You can also create a `joblet` with these two components and use the `joblet` in every job so you do not have to recreate it every time.

The diagram below shows a real simple case where I add `tLogCatcher` and `tSendMail` directly to the job.  When there is an error it will send me an email with the details.  You can use any of the columns in `row11`, I am only using job and message in my example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error :   `For input string "fabrik"`
 is generated by the tFileInputExcel component when encountering a non valid field (expected : integer ; given : string). You can't directly catch this error with the tFileInputExcel component (it's just printed out on the console).

However, you can use a tSchemaComplianceCheck component after your tFileInputExcelComponent : it will throw an error if a data is not valid for your schema. This component has a reject link to catch the error.

```
tFileInputExcel->tSchemaComplianceCheck->tMap->tMSOutput
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use tLogCatcher component to catch the error then, at the end of the flow, you can add a tBufferOutput component. Keep the fields with the information you want for.
[component configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74DB6.png)

The result will be like this (note that they are shown in the same order):
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrN49.png)